# error: more than one device/emulator - cant remove unity emulator

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb

Im trying to get debug info through logcat when developing for android. Logcat does not show any info but only an error

`error: more than one device/emulator`

When i run command

```
adb devices
```

i get

```
List of devices attached
R3CT20DP74P     device
emulator-5562   offline
```

I guess the emulator is preventing my phone from connecting with adb? Im also guessing thats what causing catlog from logging from my phone. Do i remove the emulator -5562 somehow? Ive tried  adb kill-server but the emulator reapears.

Ive also tried

```
adb -s emulator-5562 emu kill
```

returns:

```
error: could not connect to TCP port 5562: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5562: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

Ive tried:
adb.exe -s R3CT20DP74P forward tcp:7201 tcp:7201

which returns

```
7201
```

but does nothing else. Emulator is still there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are 2 separate errors that you're getting, and they actually have nothing to do with each other. You'll need to deal with both of them:

**error: more than one device/emulator**:
you need to run `adb kill-server` to clear the connected devices, and then restart ADB. It'll auto-connect any devices that are physically connected via USB, but it won't connect any emulators or devices that are connected via wireless debugging

**error: could not connect to TCP port**: it looks like you're trying to connect via wireless debugging, and it's a bit finicky. It times out after a while, and the device starts rejecting your connection requests. To fix it, you have to physically connect your device to the PC using a USB cable, and as soon as you do that, it should give you a confirmation prompt on the device to allow the USB debugging connection. After you approve that request, you'll need to turn off wireless debugging, and then turn it right back on. It'll generate a new TCP port for you to use, and you will now be able to connect to wireless debugging using that new port

Comment: thanks for your time. The second error is not really something im trying to achieve i got it when i just tried a solution i read on the internet. As for the first error, ive tried kill-server many times. It does what you describe but the emulator auto reconnects each time. Its gone for  some seconds but then shows up again. I dont understand where it is coming from or how to disactivate it. Is  there some way to find out?

Comment: you should shut the emulator down, then adb kill-server